# Convert the seconds since epoch to date

Tags: algorithm, assembly

How can i convert the seconds from EPOCH to date format in assembly?

here is my attempt:

```
    ;get the system date
    mov     dword eax, [ebx+0]
    push    eax
    xor     edx, edx
    mov     edi, 86400
    div     edi             ;1day=86400secs, remainder in edx
    add     edx, 4          ;day 0 was Thursday
    mov     eax, edx
    xor     edx, edx
    mov     edi, 7
    div     edi             ;find the day of the week
    mov     [wday], edx
```

By the way do i divide correctly (in order to get the remainder in edx)?
Basically, this code yields the correct number for the day (1 for sunday).So how can i compute the number of the month?

Comment: If it's not homework, it's masochism.

Comment: hehe...no its not a homework, actually its a trying to implement an algorithm i have found in the net for something else but i must calculate the day and month first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend working this out in a higher-level language before trying it in assembly.  Date math is too convoluted and irregular to be designing your algorithm directly in assembly.

You've already got the number of days since the Epoch by dividing by 86400.  Since the number of days in a year vary, you need to figure out what year you're in (and how many days into the year).  The conceptually simplest way to do that is to take it year by year -- subtract 366 if a leap year, 365 otherwise, until you have less than a year's worth of days.  Then you can do the same month by month (subtract 31, or 30, or 29, or 28!).  There are potential optimizations, of course, but those can come later.

As for your current code... I think you're accidentally using the number of seconds past midnight of the current day, instead of the number of days, when trying to calculate the day of the week.  (In other words, you should be working with eax after that first div, rather than edx.)  Also keep in mind that the remainder is going to range from 0 to 6, so if you want a [1..7] range, you should add 1 afterwards.